# Python 3.x multiprocessing tkinter mainloop

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-multiprocessing, traceback

How do you use `multiprocessing` on `root.mainloop`?  I am using Python 3.6.  I need to do lines of code after it, some requiring the object.
I **do not want to create a second object**, like some of the other answers for my question suggest.
Here is a little code snippet (set being a JSON object):

```
from multiprocessing import Process
def check():
    try: sett['setup']
    except KeyError:
        sett['troubleshoot_file']=None
        check()
    else:
        if sett['setup'] is True: return
        elif type(sett['setup']) is not bool: raise TypeError('sett[\'setup\'] is not a type of boolian (\'bool\')')
    root.=Tk()
    root['bg']='blue'
    mainloop=Process(target=root.mainloop)
    mainloop.start()
    mainloop.join()
check()
```

However, I get this traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "(directory)/main.py", line 41, in <module>
    check()
  File "(directory)/main.py", line 39, in check
    mainloop.start()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 105, in start
    self._popen = self._Popen(self)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 223, in _Popen
    return _default_context.get_context().Process._Popen(process_obj)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 322, in _Popen
    return Popen(process_obj)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\multiprocessing\popen_spawn_win32.py", line 65, in __init__
    reduction.dump(process_obj, to_child)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 60, in dump
    ForkingPickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
TypeError: can't pickle _tkinter.tkapp objects
```

I have tried running:

```py
from queue import Queue
from tkinter import Tk
from multiprocessing import Process
p=Process(target=q.get())
```

The interpreter then completely crashes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use any tkinter objects across multiple processes or threads. If you need to share data between the gui and other processes you will need to set up a queue, and poll the queue from the GUI.

The reason for this is that tkinter is a wrapper around a tcl interpreter that knows nothing about python threads or processes.

You will find a link on how to do this at:
[docs.python.org/3.6/library/queue.html](http://docs.python.org/3.6/library/queue.html)

Comment: Please tell me how to create a queue.

Comment: I was doing it in IDLE on 3.6, is that the problem?

Comment: @Anynomous: it is absolutely impossible for me to know, when all I have to go on is "it didn't work". That could mean any of a thousand different things.

Comment: Here is the code: `from queue import Queue` `from tkinter import Tk` `from multiprocessing import Process` `p=Process(target=q.get())`  Then, the interpreter stops and even keyboard interrupts don't start it.